# ngFor not working and no error in console

Tags: json, angular, ngfor

*user.service.ts*

```
@Injectable()
 export class UserService  {constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    console.log("in users http Get request");
    return this.http.get("/assets/users.json")
   .map((res: Response) => res.json());
```

*user.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component ({
    selector: 'users',
    providers: [UserService],
       template :`<div>
   <table>
    <tr *ngIf="!users || users.length==0"> Unable to load data </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of users" style="border:1px solid red">
      <td>{{user.id}}</td>
      <td>{{users.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    </div>`
   })

export class User{   //created user class with properties
    UserService: Observable<User[]>;
    user: string;
    constructor(public service1:UserService) {

   } 
  ngOnInit() {
      console.log("in ngoninnit");
      this.UserService = this.service1.getUsers();
    }   
}
```

*users.json*

```
 [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-43.9509",
        "lng": "-34.4618"
      }

  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Clementine Bauch",
    "username": "Samantha",
    "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
    "address": {
      "street": "Douglas Extension",
      "suite": "Suite 847",
      "city": "McKenziehaven",
      "zipcode": "59590-4157",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-68.6102",
        "lng": "-47.0653"
      }

  }
]
```

---

I am getting below result:

```
Unable to load data
ID  Name
```

Not getting the users data.

Comment: Your `ngFor` is trying to loop through a collection called `users`, but I can't see that you've created a variable called `this.users` anywhere in your .ts file

Comment: Side note: shouldn't this be singular (user instead of userS): <td>{{users.name}}</td>

Comment: this are really basic errors, you should take the tour of heroes to gain a better understanding of some basic concepts https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Beside the typos, you are not calling subscribe anywhere:

```
export class User{   //created user class with properties
    UserService: Observable<User[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
      this.UserService = this.service1.getUsers();
    }   
}
```

Since you're saving the observable, you must use async to trigger getting the data:

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users | async"
```